# Distinct duplicate values of one column and add unique values to another column with comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below data

[image]

I want to find distinct duplicate values of one column and add unique values to another column with a comma.

Comment: Please click one example to view my required output.

Comment: Dear sir, I am new in slq so i am not getting solution

Comment: select  col1, stuff(
(
SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + col2
          FROM table
          WHERE [col1] = a.[col1] 
          FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')AS col2
    FROM table AS a
GROUP BY col1

Comment: Thank You Antony Sir It works nice. Thanks again. :)